Permissions for CustomContainerTrainingJob on GCP Vertex AI notebook
I'm running this huggingface example notebook for Vertex AI in Colab Enterprise:
https://github.com/huggingface/Google-Cloud-Containers/blob/main/examples/vertex-ai/notebooks/trl-lora-sft-fine-tuning-on-vertex-ai/vertex-notebook.ipynb
We've managed to enable all necessary IAM permissions for my user account up to the final cell, but obviously missing some permissions to execute the submit() method. All details are correct (bucket name, project, etc) and work in previous cells.
The most recent permission we tried adding was: (this didn't work)
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project-name --member=user:me@example.com --role=roles/aiplatform.user

Code in notebook:
# a previous cell...
job = aiplatform.CustomContainerTrainingJob(
    display_name="trl-lora-sft",
    container_uri=os.getenv("CONTAINER_URI"),
    command=[
        "sh",
        "-c",
        'exec trl sft "$@"',
        "--",
    ],
)

###############

# final cell causes error:
job.submit(
    args=args,
    replica_count=1,
    machine_type="g2-standard-12",
    accelerator_type="NVIDIA_L4",
    accelerator_count=1,
    base_output_dir=f"{os.getenv('BUCKET_URI')}/Mistral-7B-v0.3-LoRA-SFT-Guanaco",
    environment_variables={
        "HF_HOME": "/root/.cache/huggingface",
        "HF_TOKEN": get_token(),
        "TRL_USE_RICH": "0",
        "ACCELERATE_LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
        "TRANSFORMERS_LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
        "TQDM_POSITION": "-1",
    },
    timeout=60 * 60 * 3,  # 3 hours (10800s)
    create_request_timeout=60 * 10,  # 10 minutes (600s)
)

Error message:
PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project 'my-project-name'. [links {
  description: "Google developers console"
  url: "https://console.developers.google.com"
}
, reason: "CONSUMER_INVALID"
domain: "googleapis.com"
metadata {
  key: "consumer"
  value: "projects/\'my-project-name\'"
}
metadata {
  key: "service"
  value: "aiplatform.googleapis.com"
}
]

